# bootstrap advanced input with email domain

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I want to create a specific email input box.
For example, let's assume the user's email is kbs4674@naver.com. Now, when user just enters the email id, "kbs4674", and if user clicks that 'submit' button, the email is updated (automatically) to  'kbs4674@naver.com'.

I want the input to look like this!

[image]

▲ In Picture, '@naver.com' is fixed (can't modified)

```
<div class="field col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-5" align="left">
<%= f.label :Email %><br />
</div>
<div class="input-group field col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-5">
<%= f.text_field :email, class: "input-group-addon", pattern: "[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}", aria: { describedby: "basic-addon2"}, autofocus: true, :required => true %>
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@naver.com</span>
</div><br/>
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. (it just transefer ID date 'kbs4674', not 'kbs4674@naver.com')

What is the issue with my code?

Comment: "It doesn't work".. in what way? What is the expected behaviour

Comment: I want this  : if input in form 'kbs4674' and click 'submit' button, It transfer 'kbs4674@naver.com'

Comment: Umm In detail, I don't want use pattern, it means... Don't type the email domain user-self

Comment: And what is happening now that differs from that behaviour? In other words, what is transfering instead of "kbs4674@naver.com"? Please add these details to your question so it is more likely users understand better and help you

Comment: I mean, I want make it : called 'ID' input is typed by user's ID(not full-email with domain), and if click 'submit' button, it is automatically transfer 'kbs4674@fixed email domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version of why it's not working as intended is because the input group add-on in bootstrap isn't an add-on to the input itself, it's just for decoration. When you submit the form it's just going to send what's in the input field and not care about what's in the `<span class="input-group-addon"></span>`.

One easy way to handle this: You can append `@naver.com` to the param using string interpolation in the controller method that handles the form submission with a line something like this:

```
user_email = "#{params[:email]}@naver.com"
```

While the form won't sent `kbs4674@naver.com`, you will still get control over the domain of the email, without having to worry about a wily user cracking into your JS and changing up the email domain.